# Как установить React-PHP-V8Js?

Tags: php, reactjs

Что нужно сделать чтобы начать пользоваться React-PHP-V8Js? Система у меня win7.

Answer (score 0):

Установка - https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/master/README.Win32.md

Использование:

```
    // the library
$react_source = file_get_contents('/path/to/build/react.js');
// all custom code concatenated
$app_source = file_get_contents('/path/to/custom/components.js');

$rjs = new ReactJS($react_source, $app_source);
$rjs->setComponent('MyComponent', array(
  'any'   =>  1,
  'props' =>  2
  )
);

/// ...

// print rendered markup
echo '<div id="here">' . $rjs->getMarkup() . '</div>';

/// ...

// load JavaScript somehow - concatenated, from CDN, etc
// including react.js and custom/components.js

// init client
echo '<script>' . $rjs->getJS("#here") . '</script>'; 

/// ...

// repeat setComponent(), getMarkup(), getJS() as necessary
// to render more components
```